# Why is the vii° in minor not labelled with a # sign?

Tags: chord-theory

In minor the vii° is built on a raised leading tone and this note is indicated by a sharp or natural sign. However, the chord itself is labelled vii° not #vii°. Why is the note labelled in the score with an accidental but not in the chord label?

Answer (score 4):

Kostka and Payne explain this as a convention: chords in a minor key are labeled according to the harmonic minor scale. In practice, I would guess that the main reason is that the diminished chord on the lower step 7 is very rare (I've never seen one). The diminished on the upper step 7 is very common; it's also the same notes as V7 with the root missing (and is also used as such quite often.)

Comment: What convention? The theory books my Royal Conservatory of Music theory teachers got me to read used, in minor keys, both vii°7 and VII, with vii°7 starting on the leading tone and VII starting on the subtonic.

Comment: That's the convention. The Roman numerals in a minor key are based on the scale steps of the Harmonic minor (with VII being the lower step 7). While melodies in a minor key often use both forms of both steps 6 and 7, the chords tend to be used a little more restrictively. The point is to use the most economical abbreviations.

Comment: @ttw - But if minor-key chords were truly "labeled according to the harmonic minor scale", wouldn't we use bVII instead?

Comment: Yes. That's why it's called conventional rather than "exactly musically derived."

Comment: And how is the vii°6 in minor notated using roman numerals and figured bass? wont the 6 have to be sharpened?